# Check for a Valid Instance of in NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, class-validator

I'v'e been trying to validate my request based on my entity (Product) dto.
Everything is working fine, except for 'From' and 'To' fields.
Customer and Type fields are validated correctly, if i try to send a request with wrong data, that's what i get.

```
"statusCode": 400,
"message": [
    "type must be a valid enum value"
],
"error": "Bad Request"
```

**Expected Behavior**
ProductDto should validate 'From' and 'To' fields from LeagueEntity.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `@Type(() => LeagueEntity)` to your `from` and `to` properties so that `class-transformer` and `class-validator` know what they are properly validating. As these are sub classes, you'll probably want to add `@ValidateNested()` as well

Comment: It worked! I would like to know the resources where you get this info, so i can learn, thanks.

Comment: [clas-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) and [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) docs on GitHub